# SIGSTOP after few minutes listening on a background socket

Tags: ios

I have a background cocoaasyncsocket socket running on background.

```
//DELEGATE
- (void) socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag
{
    self.i += 1;
    NSLog(@"didReadData %d %@", self.i, [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
    [self.asyncSocket readDataWithTimeout:-1 tag:0];

}

- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didConnectToHost:(NSString *)host port:(UInt16)port 
{
    NSLog(@"socket:%p didConnectToHost:%@ port:%hu", sock, host, port);

    [self.asyncSocket performBlock:^{
        [self.asyncSocket enableBackgroundingOnSocket];
    }];

    [self.asyncSocket readDataWithTimeout:-1 tag:0];

}
```

//.plist

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>voip</string>
</array>
```

it works fine for the first 3 minutes afterwords I get a SIGSTOP and the app "crashes". Do you know why?

Comment: does it really crash or just stops doing anything?

Comment: did you found the problem? I have a similar issue with an app that worked fine before upgrading to xCode 4.3.2

Answer (score 6):

You can probably check the reason in the Organizer (from XCode click on Window -> Organizer -> your iOS device -> Device Logs -> your application).

In my case it was something like this:

```
Application Specific Information:
BKUnsuspendLimit MyApp[5168] exceeded 15 wakes in 300 sec
```

It turned out that there's a limit on how many times your app could be waken up in 300 sec.

Comment: Sometimes the simplest advice is the best.  Wish I could give you more than +1.

Comment: This information is still relevant and super helpful.  I am using a socket.io socket in swift on iOS 8.4 and opening the socket as a voip socket.   Found the device Log which is now located in Window > Devices > Your device on the left hand side > View Device Logs.  And some where in there was :   BKUnsuspendLimit <BKNewProcess: 0x3117b0; AppName; pid: 362; hostpid: -1> exceeded 15 wakes in 300 sec.   Sure enough thats killing my app.